# Strange redirect problem with gnumake

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, gnu-make

I have a system in which I generate a makefile and which works perfectly under Mac OS X. When I run it under Linux, I get a strange problem.  I managed to reduce my makefile to a very simple example:

```
    compile:
        gcc -o prog *.c &> compile__

    chm:
        chmod u=rwx,g=rwx,o= prog

    both0:
        gcc -o prog *.c &> compile__ ;  \
        chmod u=rwx,g=rwx,o= prog

    both1:
        gcc -o prog *.c ;  \
        chmod u=rwx,g=rwx,o= prog
```

The idea is to compile a file and then change its permissions. If I execute the command sequence:

```
    make compile
    make chm
```

everything works fine. However if I execute:

```
    make both0
```

I get the message:

```
    chmod: cannot access `prog': No such file or directory
```

and the permissions are not changed. On the other hand if I execute:

```
    make both1
```

the permissions are changed properly. The only difference is the redirection "&> compile__" under both0 which I removed for both1.

Any ideas?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I run gnumake version 3.81 under Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Works for me: CentOS release 5.4 (Final); GNU Make 3.81; gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46); hello.c;

Comment: I tested it on another Linux: Fedora release 9 (Sulphur) and the same GNU Make 3.81. No problem! It seems to occur only under my installation: Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS, kernel 2.6.32-30.

Answer (score 4):

```
&> compile__
```

is *not* a portable redirection.  In bash, it redirects both standard error and standard output, which I assume is your intention.  Other shells are likely to do different things with it.  In particular, dash backgrounds the command (the `&`), and redirects standard output (the `> compile__`).  The `chmod` is executed before the compile finishes and creates `prog`.  Redirecting both standard error and standard output  can be done portably with `cc -o prog *.c > compile__ 2>&1`.

(Why did it work on the mac?  Possibly a different shell that interprets `&>` differently, possible the compiler opening the file earlier, possibly a race condition coming out slightly differently.)

Comment: In bash, '`&>`' redirects both stdout and stderr to the same file; it has no backgrounding effect.

Comment: The three systems I tested (Mac OS, Fedora and Ubuntu) use the same GNU Bash, so they should not behave differently.

Comment: Make uses the system's /bin/sh, which may not be bash.  Ubuntu systems generally use "dash" for /bin/sh.  Dash does indeed background, and runs an empty command redirecting to "compile__"  @Tsf: humor me and try switching it to '> compile__ 2>&1', the standard way to do this redirection.

Comment: I humored you and it worked but I still don't understand why! If my syntax is wrong, than the target "compile" of my makefile shouldn't work. On the other hand, my bash manual says:
 
There are two formats for redirecting standard output and standard error:

     &>word
and

     >&word
Of the two forms, the first is preferred. This is semantically equivalent to

     >word 2>&1

As far as I know, my system is using bash and not dash.  Thanks for solving my immediate problem, but I still would like to understand what is going on!

Comment: @Tsf:  Different shells support different syntax.  Your *user* shell is undoubtedly bash, which supports that syntax.  Make (by default, anyway) uses the system shell, which appears to not support that syntax in Ubuntu.  The syntax is "correct" in so much as bash supports it, but "incorrect" in so much as other shells do not.  What can definitely be said is that this syntax is "non-standard".  This bit of syntax was not in the original Bourne shells, but came from csh.  Well `>&` did, bash added `&>` as well -- it's less widely supported and I don't know why the bash manual would recommend it.

Comment: The target `compile` works because the syntax is not a syntax _error_, it's interpreted differently than you intended.

Comment: @wnoise: I am not sure I understand you: the target `compile` does exactly what I want it to do, regardless of the syntax chosen!

Comment: @wnoise: I think I might have been too fast in my answer -- it seems that there is a difference in interpretation! I guess I will stick to scons in place of make whenever I can.

Comment: @Tsf: No, it doesn't, but the distinction is hard to see when only one command executes.  The command backgrounds itself, and does not redirect standard error.  The backgrounding doesn't matter much when it's the only command in a rule, and you call it directly from the command line -- it eventually finishes.  The problems come when some other command depends on this output, either in the same rule (how you noticed it), or another rule.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution is to specify the *shell* for GNU `make` to use.  [Section *5.3.1*](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Choosing-the-Shell) of the manual has information on this.  For instance, the following

```
export SHELL=`which bash`
```

In a *Makefile* seems to get Gnu Make 3.8.1 on Ubuntu/Debian to choose *bash* as the shell.

Other issues are differences in the behaviour of all the shell *built-in's*, like `echo`, `printf`, `test`, etc.  Esoteric options to these *built-in's* may mysteriously fail when run under `make` on Debian based systems.